# Parsing large strings in python

Tags: python, string-matching

I am trying to parse a string extract specific words.

The string

```
{{About|the ALGOL-like programming language|the scripting language formerly named Small|Pawn (scripting language)}}

'''SMALL''', Small Machine Algol Like Language, is a [[computer programming|programming]] [[programming language|language]] developed by Dr. [[Nevil Brownlee]] of [[Auckland University]].

==History==
The aim of the language was to enable people to write [[ALGOL]]-like code that ran on a small machine.  It also included the '''string''' type for easier text manipulation.

SMALL was used extensively from about 1980 to 1985 at [[Auckland University]] as a programming teaching aid, and for some internal projects.  Originally written to run on a [[Burroughs Corporation]] B6700 [[Main frame]] in [[Fortran]] IV, subsequently rewritten in SMALL and ported to a DEC [[PDP-10]] Architecture (on the [[Operating System]] [[TOPS-10]]) and IBM S360 Architecture (on the Operating System VM/[[Conversational Monitor System|CMS]]).

About 1985, SMALL had some [[Object-oriented programming|object-oriented]] features added to handle structures (that were missing from the early language), and to formalise file manipulation operations.

==See also==
*[[ALGOL]]
*[[Lua (programming language)]]
*[[Squirrel (programming language)]]

==References==
*[http://www.caida.org/home/seniorstaff/nevil.xml Nevil Brownlee]

[[Category:Algol programming language family]]
[[Category:Systems programming languages]]
[[Category:Procedural programming languages]]
[[Category:Object-oriented programming languages]]
[[Category:Programming languages created in the 1980s]]
```

I want to extract ALGOL, Lua (programming language), Squirrel(programming language) from the SEE ALSO section. (Exactly these words are to added no brackets or star.)
I have tried these Approaches 
String split, regular expressions. 
I am still nowhere, 
Help appreciated.

Code used by me

```
import urllib.request,json,re

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=SMALL&prop=revisions&rvprop=content"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
str_response = response.readall().decode('utf-8')
obj = json.loads(str_response)
a=str(obj['query']['pages']['1808130']['revisions'][0]['*'])
print(a)
```

String is stored in a.

Comment: What have you tried *exactly*? I'd say you could split the string into lines, extract all lines between `==See also==` and the next section (or end of file) and then apply a suitable regular expression to every line.

Comment: it's not json, so how could that work?

Comment: How do you @FrerichRaabe suggest i extract all lines between ==See Also== and the next section ? using regular expression ?? I wrote a regular expression for the lines in the middle. i.e. "\W\W\W[a-z,A-Z\W]+\W\W"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you need characters between `==See also==` and `==References==` excluding those `*[]` . I named your initial string as `my_string`.

```
import re

# Sliced_string will only contain the characters between '==See also==' and '==References=='
sliced_string = re.findall(r'==See also==(.*?)==References==', my_string, re.DOTALL)[-1]

# Removes stars and brackets
for unwanted_char in '[]*':
    sliced_string = sliced_string.replace(unwanted_char, '')

# Creates a list of strings (also removes empty strings)
final_list = sliced_string.split('\n')
final_list = [elem for elem in final_list if elem != '']

print(final_list)
```

**Edit**: Converted string to a list.

Code works correctly assuming there is only one occurrence of `==See also==` and `==References==` in given string.

Comment: Does the job perfectly... Could you explain the regex you have applied ? I am not used to such complicated regex

Comment: Firstly, you should use raw strings like `r'something'` instead of `'something'`. 

Now about the regex; parenthesis indicate which part of the match you want `findall` to return (it will match the whole pattern, but only return the parenthesis content). 

Dot `.` means _any character excluding a new line_. If `re.DOTALL` is used as flag, then it ll match new lines as well. 
 
Star `*` means _from 0 to infinite characters_. If it's `*?` then it will match as few as possible before it reaches `==References==`.

Comment: For more details you can check https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html, or ask.

Comment: (Just to make it clear, i meant using raw strings for regex patterns, not in general)

Answer (score 1):

```
print  re.findall(r"\*\[\[([^\]]*)\]\]",re.findall(r"==See also==((?:\s+\*\[\[(?:[^\]]*)\]\])+)",x)[0])
```

Apply this directly and send your string stored in x.